# Scandit python code 15 Your app ID does not match the license key's app ID

Tags: python, barcode-scanner

I am using a barcode scanner, scandit 5.14.2 on Linux with a trial license. I am trying to run a python module sample i.e. `CommandLineBarcodeScannerImageProcessingSample.py` but I am getting the following error

> Processing frame failed with code 15: The Scandit SDK license
>   validation failed. Your app ID does not match the license key's app
>   ID.

I have tried creating a new license key with Application ID / Bundle ID as the name of the file i.e. `CommandLineBarcodeScannerImageProcessingSample.py` but still getting the same error.
Same goes with `CommandLineBarcodeScannerCameraSample.py` but all c scripts run fine.

In FAQs of scandit it is mentioned that I should use program_invocation_name as bundle id. Is there something I am missing? Any suggestion would be very helpful

Comment: I think error clearly mentions `Your app ID does not match the license key's app ID.` So should be checked that.

Comment: In the Scandit document, it is mentioned that use program_invokation_name as app id in Linux. I have tried it but it's still not working

Comment: can you point me to library you are using?

Comment: @Kishan https://www.scandit.com/

Answer (score 1):

I know it´s a little bit late, but I think I found a solution for the problem.

I experienced exactly the same issues and could fix it with creating a new licencse key with the Bundle ID 'python3'. Then you have to use the generated license key in your python samples.

Let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

One does not need to create a new license ID for sample code from Scandit. One needs do the following:

1. login to your dashboard
2. go to the License Keys tab. There is a default license key already made. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

if you use android app, you need to check the app id inside the object defaultConfig on key androindId. That value must match with the bundle ID in scandist dashboard.