# Can scandit run with expo(react-native)?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, scandit

I've tried the docs, but it only goes into setting up a react-native project. It has samples and I've tried many combinations to get it to work, but all end up resulting generally in the same errors...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Defaults' of null, js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

Keep in mind, `expo` does not have an android folder, and relies on the plugins in the node_modules to run it on android simulator or your android phone using expo app.

*note:* the errors are the same weather I run it on my android simulator, or my android galaxy s20 device.
[image]

I've also tried running the sample projects by themselves, but those come with their own errors I wasn't able to solve either.

Comment: Proof if you can use https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/,
if you really need to use scandit you can use it with expo with Prebuild (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/) and config plugins (https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/introduction/)

Comment: @MichaelBahl I followed all the docs, and all give me different build errors. I hacked away multiple config files to force different versions until it finally builded, but with errors like the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665224/scandit-python-code-15-your-app-id-does-not-match-the-license-keys-app-id. This is becoming way more complicated than it needs to be. I'm wondering if it can be done at this point.